# ionic 2 returning {"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":"cyprus"}

Tags: angular, typescript, cordova, ionic2, ionic3

i have my function in a provider page called api-serive.ts

```
//get city in profile 
    getCityInProfile(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

            let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization':  
             localStorage.getItem('token') });

            this.http.get(this.getProfile,{headers:headers}).subscribe(
                (res) => {
                    console.log (res.json().profile.location)
                    resolve(res.json().profile.location)
                    return  (resolve(res.json().profile.location));
                },(err) => {
                    reject(err);
                }); 
        })

    }
```

when i call this function in another page.ts to get the city in my profile it returns this:

> {"__zone_symbol__state":null,"__zone_symbol__value":"cyprus"}

and this is how I call it in my page.ts

> CityInProfile(){      console.log
>   (JSON.stringify(this.jobsServiceProvider.getCityInProfile() )+
>   'returned')
>         this.cityProfile=this.jobsServiceProvider.getCityInProfile();   }

the value is there (cyprus) but why is it being returned that way

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to keep in mind that the service is getting data *in an asynchronous way* so you have to wait for that data to be ready.

If you don't mind, I'd make a few small changes to your code:

```
// Get city in profile 
getCityInProfile(): Promise<any> {

    // First get the token from the localStorage (it's async!)
    return localStorage.getItem('token').then(token => {

        // Set the token in the header
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization':  token });

        // Make the request, but don't subscribe here!
        return this.http.get(this.getProfile, { headers:headers })
                        .map(res => res.json())
                        .map(resJson => resJson.profile.location)
                        .toPromise();

    });
}
```

Then when you want to use that service, you'd need to do it like this:

```
public getCityInProfile(): void {

    // Use the 'then' to wait for the response to be ready
    this.jobsServiceProvider.getCityInProfile().then(city => {

        // Now you can use the city returned by the service
        console.log(`Returned: ${city}`);
        this.cityProfile = city;

    });

}
```